# jQuery set DIV text

Tags: jquery, image-loading

I'm having trouble with my code... I have a feeling its merely a careless error... but I cannot, for the life of me, find it. Here's my code:

```
            var now = new Date();
            var url = "out.jpg?" + now.getTime();
            im = $("<img>");
            im.hide();
            im.bind("load",function(){ $(this).fadeIn(); });
            $('#target').append(im);
            im.attr('src',url);
```

This works fine; however I call this code in a loop, and it appends the image over and over and over... I tried using:

```
    $('#target').text(im);
```

But that had no effect... Help anyone?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You are adding a new image to #target in this code so if you loop over it multiple times you are quite rightly going to have multiple images created and appended. What is the purpose of the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the target is supposed to contain only this image, you can use html

```
 $('#target').html(im);
```

and that would replace the content with the image.

Comment: Why the upvotes? Note that `im` isn't an HTML string - it's a jQuery object with event handlers bound.

Comment: @Box9: The `.html()` method can handle a jQuery object (oddly enough).

Answer (score 0):

You want to `.empty()` the div, before `.append()`:

```
$('#target').empty().append(im);
```